# How to create Universal app for iOS?

Tags: ios, universal

I need to create universal app for iPhone 3.5, 4.0, 4.7, 5.5 inches mobile and iPad. Also i wish to know which is the best way whether to create programatically or to use storyboard. I am using xcode-6.

Comment: Adaptive layout https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/mobilehig/LayoutandAppearance.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When creating a new project, you need to specify for which device you want to build the app, having the options **iPhone**, **iPad** and **Universal**. So, in your case you need to specify **Universal**.

[image]

As for the question whether or not to use **Storyboards**, it depends a bit on your app. But especially when you want to go for all devices and device sizes, I guess it's a good idea to use **Storyboards** and then also make use of **Autolayout** and **Size classes** to adapt your UI to the different screen sizes.

Comment: Actually i meant the designing. I am creating login screen so i use button textfield and label. When i align those objects with constraints it looks different in different size of screen. I don't know how to overcome those issue. Also i am new to xcode 6 and size class.

Comment: then your question is too broad and opinion-based, which is why it has been put on hold. i recommend you to go check on some tutorials to get into the autolayout and size classes as these are the technologies you'll want to use to achieve your goal :)